# Flutter Request failed Google Pay live mode using Stripe Payment

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

Google pay is completely working on Test mode but after set the live secret key in "v1/payment_intents" in this API so it's not working and getting the below error. I'm using the [Stripe plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe).

```
Future<void> startGooglePay() async {
    final googlePaySupported = await Stripe.instance.isGooglePaySupported(IsGooglePaySupportedParams(testEnv: 
    false));
     if (googlePaySupported) {
    try {
       // 1. fetch Intent Client Secret from backend
     final response = await fetchPaymentIntentClientSecret();
   print(response);
       final clientSecret = response['client_secret'];

 // 2.present google pay sheet

await Stripe.instance.initGooglePay(GooglePayInitParams( merchantName: "Test Name",
    countryCode: 'US',testEnv: false));

await Stripe.instance.presentGooglePay(PresentGooglePayParams(clientSecret: clientSecret,currencyCode: "GBP"),);

await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
    googlePay: PaymentSheetGooglePay(merchantCountryCode: 'US'),
    paymentIntentClientSecret: response['client_secret'],
    setupIntentClientSecret:response['client_secret'],
    customerEphemeralKeySecret: response['client_secret'],
    customerId:PLPrefrence.getPrefValue(key: PLPrefrence.user_code).toString()
));

await Stripe.instance.retrievePaymentIntent(response['client_secret']).then((value){

  print(value.id);
  print(value.status);
  print(value.confirmationMethod.name);

});


 } catch (e) {
   print('ErrorStripePrint : ${e}');

  errorDialog(errorMessage: "$e");
  }
  } else {
    errorDialog(errorMessage: "Google pay is not supported on this device");
     }
}
```

Now here is the API call for payment_intents API

```
 Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchPaymentIntentClientSecret() async {
   final url = Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents');
   Map<String, dynamic> body = {
     'amount':calculateAmount(amount:  _plController.isUseWalletbalance.value ? 
  _plController.processedAmount.value : widget.grandTotal.toString()).toString(),
   'currency': "GBP",
   'payment_method_types[]': 'card',

   };

   final response = await http.post(
     url,
     headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${PLKeys.stripeSK_Live}',
    },
    body: body,
   );

return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

if I set the testEnv true and test secret key in so it's working but set testEnv false and set stripe live mode secret key so it's not working and getting issue as upload image above.

Error Image:-
[image]

Comment: There is additional configuration/setup required to use Google Pay on Android in a live environment. This is documented [here on Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay?platform=android#going-live), however the configuration is done in your Google Admin UI. Have you taken these steps?

Comment: Thanks @JonathanSteele 
I have got the approval from Google pay ( https://prnt.sc/9wknuMREsxdi )  but still getting the same error as I attach the screenshot. So why I'm getting still this error in release android build. Please help me

Comment: I'd recommend writing in to Stripe [support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) for more help!